# Rails app is deployed and on, but bundle not seeing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, bundler, ansible

I use Rails 4 in my app and am deploying it using Ansible&Capistrano.

As an Ansible template I use playbook pretty similar to this one - https://github.com/JohnnyR1co/fashcards/blob/master/config/provision/playbook.yml

It installs ruby as well as anything else and After `cap production deploy` I am able to see app on (I can load some non-db related pages).

But when I try to run something like `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` from the current folder I get

`The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: apt-get install <selected package>`

Why is this so? App is up and running, so rails seem to be fine.

Also when I try to run `bundle install` I get an error that nokogiri is not installed, despite I installed it manually after deploy. What could be the reason here?

I believe problem could be in `playbook.yml`file. Ruby installation is done there and I am not sure how correct is it.

Comment: Have you tried `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` to open the console?

Comment: Yes, this gives me  `bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with "bundle install"`

Comment: see this post similar :  https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2291

Comment: Nothing from this thread seems to be working, same errors. I believe problem could be in `playbook.yml`file. Ruby installation is done there and I am not sure how correct is it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

Comment: this gives `bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with "bundle install"`

And when I try to bundle, I get an error that nokogiri gem is not installed (which is not true)

Comment: check if you have all gems installed there